# Flink job status metrics being reset during checkpoint restoration process

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

We are running a flink job inside the Kubernetes cluster. We are storing the checkpoint in ADLS in Azure. If there is an error we are able to restore the checkpoint from ADLS. But while restoring the checkpoint, all the matrices in Flink are getting reset.

[image]

Bytes Received, Bytes send and records sent all reset to zero. Is it normal or I am losing any data while the checkpoint restoration process? The checkpoint size is incrementally increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Flink's metrics are re-initialized each time a job is started; they aren't checkpointed or restored. This is normal.

It's common for checkpoint sizes to increase over time. This can happen because there's more active data to checkpoint (as the number of keys being managed increases, for example), and/or because of the way that RocksDB gradually accumulates stale state until it is eventually compacted away.